# How to get flutter local notification on iOS using only FCM data message?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I have an app that send notifications if someone commented or published a new post. I use FCM and flutter local notification. It works well on Android, but on iOS it does not. I realized if I add a 'notification' message block to the firebase function then finally I get the data message BUT I get the notification message too at the same time. That is not what I want. If I remove Notification message then data message not triggered and I do not get any notification.
The app should works only from iOS 10+. I tried this on iOS 15.
This is my firebase function:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document("animal/{message}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("animal", {
        data: {
          latitude: snapshot.data()["latitude"].toString(),
          longitude: snapshot.data()["longitude"].toString(),
          title: snapshot.data().username,
          body: snapshot.data().description,
          uid: snapshot.data().userId,
          animalId: snapshot.id,
        },
        //I do not want to use this, but if I remove this I do not get any push notification. Data notification neither.
       //On Android it does not matter if I delete notification block or no. I will get the data notification. 
        notification: {
          title: "title",
          body: "new post",
        },
      });
    });
```

In main.dart there is the flutter local notification initializing

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final AndroidInitializationSettings _initialzationSettingsAndriod =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('noticon');
  final IOSInitializationSettings _initialzationSettingsIOS =
      IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestAlertPermission: false,
    requestBadgePermission: false,
    requestSoundPermission: false,
  );
  final InitializationSettings _initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: _initialzationSettingsAndriod, iOS: _initialzationSettingsIOS);
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    _initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: (payload) async {
      if (payload != null) {
        debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
      }
      initPayload = payload!;
      await navigatorKey.currentState!.push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AnimalDetailScreen(payload, true),
      ));
    },
  );

....

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermissions();
    final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.subscribeToTopic('animal');
    messaging.subscribeToTopic('notifications');
    messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
      provisional: false,
    );
```

And this is the showing notification. If I remove the notification message from firebase function then onMessage cannot be called on iOS but on only Android.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      print("onMessage called");
      ....
      if (isValid && currentUser != message.data['uid']) {
         showNotification(message);
         notifierCounter.value = notifierCounter.value + 1;
      }
    }

...
showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      data.hashCode,
      data['title'],
      data['body'],
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(),
      ),
      payload: data['animalId'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution.

I changed this:

```
notification: {
   title: "title",
   body: "new post",
},
```

to:

```
notification: {
   sound: "default",
},
```

In this way I wont get automatic push notification and I can handle data message on iOS.